# How to make like button in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to make like and dislike button with javascript. I'm trying to make toggle function, when clicked the button thumbs up color become dark blue, if clicked thumbs down become dark red. But it seems not working, the color is not fixed. And also I want to count the like, the user only get 1 chance vote, like or dislike.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"> 
<style>
.fa-thumbs-up:hover{
    color:darkblue;
}
.fa-up{
    color:darkblue;
}

.fa-thumbs-up:before{
    display: flex;
    margin-left: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}
    
.fa-thumbs-down:hover{
    color:darkred;
}

.fa-thumbs-down:before {
    display: flex;
    margin-left: 4px;
    }
</style>
    
<button name="button1" type="button1" style="font-size:10px">0 &nbsp | <i onclick ="myFunction()" id = "btn" class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></button> 
<button name="button2" type="button2" style="font-size:10px">0 &nbsp | <i onclick ="myFunction2()" class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></i></button>

<script>
var btn = document.getElemetById('btn');

function myFunction(){
    if(btn.classList.contains("fa")){
        btn.classList.remove("fa");
        btn.classList.add("fa-up");
    }else{
        btn.classList.remove("fa-up");
        btn.classList.add("fa");
    }
}
</script>
    
</body> </html>
```

All help is appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: "User gets one chance" .... So you will need to send data to the server and store the fact the user voted that they like it.

Comment: Did you launch the js debugger and see if clicking on an empty <i> tag caused the function to run?

Comment: "the color is not fixed." means what?

Comment: `getElemetById` - Your browser's debugging console is telling you about an error here.

Comment: `{
  "message": "Uncaught TypeError: document.getElemetById is not a function",`

Comment: actually, i have the database of user in phpmyadmin. Is it possible to insert like / dislike data? I'm still new to javascript, so I don't know how to do it. @epascarello

Comment: Sorry for my bad english, I mean, when clicked, the color stay, but if clicked again the color gone. That what I want. @epascarello

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated your code to work like you want:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html><html> <head> <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"> 
<style>
            button i{
                transition: .3s all ease;
            }
            .btn_up.clicked,.btn_up:hover i{
                color: darkblue;
            }
            .btn_down.clicked,.btn_down:hover i{
                color: darkred;
            }   
            .fa-thumbs-up:before{
                display: flex;
                margin-left: 4px;
                margin-bottom: 3px;
              
            }
            .fa-thumbs-down:before {
                display: flex;
                margin-left: 4px;
            }
    
            </style>
    
<button class="btn_up" onclick ="myFunction(this)" name="button1" type="button1" style="font-size:10px">0 &nbsp | <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></button> 
<button class="btn_down" onclick ="myFunction(this)" name="button2" type="button2" style="font-size:10px">0 &nbsp | <i class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></i></button>
<script>
    var btn_up = document.querySelector('.btn_up');
    var btn_down = document.querySelector('.btn_down');

    function myFunction(elem){
        elem.classList.toggle('clicked');
        if(elem === btn_up){
            btn_down.classList.remove('clicked');
        }else{
            btn_up.classList.remove('clicked');
        }
    }
</script>
</body> </html>
```

Comment: Sorry if I asking too much, Mathieu. I know this code is right what I wanted. But, I want to learn more about javascript. Can you make button onclick = myFunction(); and then below the code be like:

function myFunction(){
// the code
}

Thank you

Comment: Sorry I'm just seeing tour comment today...
Updated my answer.